# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject for custom object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Good day to everyone!
I wonder is it possible to make UpdateSingleSalesforceObject of custom object, where Id is in the field with DataType Lookup(Contact)?
Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible but might depend on your implementation approach. Just go through the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` [guideline](https://ampscript.guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject/) to make sure you would build the correct function and remember couple more points:

1. Include all mandatory fields for the update
2. If you have to include Date datatype fields, you would need to convert it to the correct format -

```
SET @time = FormatDate(Now(), "iso")
```

3. Certain Salesforce objects enforce record-locking when a record is modified, to ensure the referential integrity of data. This applies to records that have a relationship to lookup records in a different object. If the function is used to asynchronously update multiple records (for example, the function is included in an email) and the object has lock contention, the records may fail to update.

Comment: I got such Error
Error Message: "Call to update the salesforceobject Consent__c ID = 0033j00003oWipCAAS failed! Error status code: INVALID_ID_FIELD\nError message: '0033j00003oWipC' is not a valid Salesforce ID for the type Consent
It looks like that 3 last characters from Id were deleted. Should I use 15 characters instead of 18?

Comment: No, 18-characters format should be sufficient, yet I would assume you are using incorrect either ID value or field that correlates to the ID.

Comment: Thank you. You were right, I tried to use ID of the Contact, not of the custom Object.